# SSL error- Connention reset by peer on using Generate Certificates for ios builds

Tags: codenameone

We are able to successfully logged in using "Generate" button. After selecting and click on next button the following error is stopping us.

FYI, we are using direct internet connection.

Please find the screenshot of error message on generating certificates screen.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using certificate wizard that's within the Codename One Settings tool, I am unable to generate certificates. Its remains the same page after selecting developer profile. is this apple account issue? or connection issue

Comment: I think it's a connection issue, check you network firewall. I generated a certificate few hours ago without a hassle.

Comment: This was addressed and should work now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be an issue in the wizard process that we are struggling with for the past 24 hours. I was able to go thru the process to the app by retrying 6 times to login then retrying 8 or so times to finish the wizard...

Unfortunately the responsible engineer is on vacation and we've been struggling to figure out why this is happening exactly.

As of today (Oct 19th) **this was fixed** by our engineer who took time off vacation.